# c#.net button changes url by itself when clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

So I have a login page hosted in this url "http://192.168.0.23:8083/"

I made the login page as startup page with code in web.config like this

```
<defaultDocument>
  <files>
    <clear />
    <add value="Login.aspx"/>
  </files>
</defaultDocument>
```

The login page is simple AD authentication:

```
 using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "192.168.0.12"))
        {
            // validate the credentials
            isValid = pc.ValidateCredentials(Login1.UserName.ToString(), Login1.Password.ToString());
            if (isValid == true)
            {
                Application["logimi"] = Login1.UserName.ToString();
                Server.Transfer("Default.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Perdoruesi ose fjalekalimi jane gabim!')", true);
            }
        }
```

So after logging in successfully I use Server.Transfer("Default.aspx"); to go to the other page.

The code of the insert button in the 2nd page:

```
string selectedValue = RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue;

        string ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NOA_VotingConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Candidates SET Votes = Votes + 1 WHERE Id = @Id";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", selectedValue);

            con.Open();

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            con.Close();

            SqlCommand cmd2 = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd2.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Voters(IPofUser) VALUES(@IP)";
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IP", logimi);

            con.Open();

            cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();

            con.Close();

        }
        RadioButtonList1.Visible = false;
        Button1.Visible = false;
        Label1.Text = "Vota juaj u ruajt. Faleminderit.";
```

The page is opened successfully. Here I have a button that inserts something in SQL but when I click it, it changes the url from "http://192.168.0.23:8083/" to "http://192.168.0.23:8083/Default" and says 404 error.

How do I avoid this? I'm going crazy on searching.

Guys I noticed something. In local testing if I enter       http://localhost:59901/Default it goes to Default.aspx
but on IIS if enter the respective url http://192.168.0.23:8083/Default it says 404.

Maybe it's something IIS related, do I have to specify something there?

Thank you

Comment: If you post the code of your Login.aspx page, it will help me better to understand the problem.

Comment: Those URLs are using IP addresses that belong to your computer in your personal network. They don't have any meaning over internet. You need to post more code to help us understand your question better.

Comment: 404 errors occur for lost of different reasons.  Often servers just report any error as 404 to prevent hackers from getting access to site.  Is another webpage running on the PC using port 8080?  Can you access webpage from an IE browser manually?  Usually best way of find root cause is to use a sniffer like fiddler.  If IE works then  compare IE fiddler results with application fiddler results.

Comment: @KhuramNawaz added code for login but i dont think it will help much,

Comment: @fahadash i know, i wrote the urls just for you to see what happens in my screen, because with server.transfer the URL doesnt change but when i click the button (even if inside the button event is empty) it refreshes the page and the URL changes

Comment: @Elgert Post the code for your button click which causes the problem.

Comment: @CathalMF i edited the post but as i said even if i comment it all, it does the same thing

Comment: That code doesnt effect the page at all. So it shouldnt do anything. What is the front end code for this button?

Comment: @CathalMF i know its driving me crazy, this is the button code "<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Jepi" />"

Comment: @CathalMF also something else, when i use default.aspx as startup page, the button works correctly, data is inserted in sql. but when i start from login.aspx and do the server.transfer() thats when this happens